# Any quicker alternative for WP_Query "NOT IN"

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I am using the following `wp_query` to pull up a list of post, and I want to exclude a few categories of a custom taxonomy.

It works well, however Query Monitor is telling me that the query is slow.

I removed the `'tax_query'` part of the query and it sped up.

Is there a faster way to exclude these categories?

Thanks!

My Query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => array( 'recipe' ),
    'post_status'       => array( 'publish' ),
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'    => 40,
    'no_found_rows'     => true,
    'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ingredients',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            'terms'    => array( 'onion', 'pepper', 'bean' )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Is there some concept that groups the taxonomies that you don't want to display? You'd be better off with a custom taxonomy and term that you apply to the posts that you do want to display.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Currently, no. I could add a "Exclude from Loop" checkbox to the taxonomy via term meta, but wouldn't that be slower?